# React setState doesn't update toggle on click when i am using multi states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

I am a react js beginner and I am on my way of learning it . I tried the state and changing state using `setState`.it worked fine for me. But when i am trying to use multi state and i want more than one state change,its doesn't work. 
   ie:-In addition with the previouse state change,when clicking a button ,i want to toggle ON & OFF using `toggleOn`.When i am trying this, my first state change on click works fine and i can change a paragraph data where i wants.but i cant make the button toggle.

---

i am attaching my `app.js` code where my root class defines.

**first code that works fine  ###############**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';

class App extends Component {
  state={
    persons:[
      {name:'sheikha' , age : '23'},
      {name :'resmina' , age: '23'},
      {name :'alena' , age: '29'},
      {name :'dolly' , age: '25'},
    ]
  }
  switchNameHandler =() =>{
    // console.log('its clicked now!');
    this.setState({
      persons:[
        {name:'sheikha nazreen' , age : '23'},
      {name :'resmina' , age: '23'},
      {name :'alena' , age: '27'},
      {name :'dolly' , age: '25'},
      ]
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>i am a react developer</h1>
        <p>ewfkjoj</p>
        <button onClick={this.switchNameHandler}>click here to change</button>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[0].name} age={this.state.persons[0].age}/>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[1].name} age={this.state.persons[1].age}/>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[2].name} age={this.state.persons[2].age}>hoby:racing</Person>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[3].name} age={this.state.persons[3].age}/>
      </div>

    );
    // return React.createElement('div',{className:'App'},React.createElement('h1',null,'now its working?'));
  }
}

export default App;
```

**second code : using multi state is not working!** ###############

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';

class App extends React.Component {
  state={
    persons:[
      {name:'sheikha' , age : '23'},
      {name :'resmina' , age: '23'},
      {name :'alena' , age: '29'},
      {name :'dolly' , age: '25'},

    ],
    isToggleOn : true

  }
  // handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
  handleClick = (e) =>{
    // console.log('its clicked now!');
    this.setState(prevState =>({
      isToggleOn : !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }
  // this.state={isToggleOn : true};
  switchNameHandler = () =>{
    // console.log('its clicked now!');
    this.setState({
      persons:[
        {name:'sheikha nazreen' , age : '23'},
      {name :'resmina' , age: '23'},
      {name :'alena' , age: '27'},
      {name :'dolly' , age: '25'},
      ]
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>i am a react developer</h1>
        <p>ewfkjoj</p>

        <button onClick={this.switchNameHandler}>click here to change</button>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[0].name} age={this.state.persons[0].age}/>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[1].name} age={this.state.persons[1].age}/>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[2].name} age={this.state.persons[2].age}>hoby:racing</Person>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[3].name} age={this.state.persons[3].age}/>

        <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick}>{this.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</button>

      </div>

    );
    // return React.createElement('div',{className:'App'},React.createElement('h1',null,'now its working?'));
  }
}

export default App;
```

#

***my problem is i can't have button toggle.Is there anyone can help me please.Can you tell me how to re Write my code?***

Comment: in <button> you should call  the handleClick function `(e) => this.handleClick(e)`, not `(e) => this.handleClick`

Comment: please update button code, you have written `this.isToggleOn` instade of `this.state.isToggleOn`

Comment: @mtx, no need to pass parameter,it will work fine without passing paramater

Comment: @SohanPatil it would if passed as `onClick={this.handleClick}` but it is not written like this.

Comment: thank you Sohan.It worked! i just missed this.state.isToggleOn .And it doesnt need to pass any parameter.Thank you for your reply.

Comment: thank you mtx ! It doesnt need to pass any parameter

Answer (score 0):

change your code to :

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</button>
```

here, handleClick should be directly passed, if you are not passing any additional parameters.